# IPv4 failing, link-local IPv6 works

Tags: ssh, ip, lan, ipv6, ipv4

For some reason, I can't reach my laptop by SSH over WiFi on its IPv4 address, as it always just times out. However, connecting to it via link-local IPv6 works just fine.

Pinging the laptop over its respective addresses yields the same results (IPv4 times out, IPv6 works).

The laptop is running Ubuntu 20.04. What could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried to disable temporarily the firewall?